# Read feedback from commands?

Tags: python, linux, bash

I need to use the command `lsmod` to check if a mod is loaded, but I don't know how to read from it after running it. Im using `subprocess.Popen()` to run it. Any point in the right direction would be much appreciated. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you were looking for `ath` in `lsmod`, then command will be:  `lsmod | grep ath`

Using `subprocess`:

```
In [60]: c=subprocess.Popen("lsmod",stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

In [61]: gr=subprocess.Popen(["grep" ,"ath"],stdin=c.stdout,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

In [62]: print gr.communicate()[0]
ath5k                 135206  0 
ath                    19188  1 ath5k
mac80211              461261  1 ath5k
cfg80211              175574  3 ath5k,ath,mac80211
```

Comment: I wouldn't use `grep` here, but search for it by myself.

Answer (score 2):

Use `subprocess.Popen(stdout=subprocess.PIPE)`, then call `subprocess.communicate()` to read the output. Basic usage:

```
process = subprocess.Popen(['lsmod'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE) # Can also capture stderr
result_str = process.communicate()[0]  # Or [1] for stderr
```

See [the Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use [`subprocess.check_output()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output)?

Answer (score 0):

lsmod won't tell you this. You have to parse its output.

Take a look at https://github.com/agrover/python-kmod/ if you are wiling to use external modules.